# Set number of free events for members

Tags: civievent, civimember

I'm creating a wordpress site for a gym. The gym memberships are tiered. Platinum members can access as many classes as they like as part of their membership. They are easy to handle with CiviDisount - I just give those members 100% discount on event (class) bookings. 
Other membership tiers are harder for me to figure out. The gold membership includes 12 classes a month. How do I limit the number of events a member can access based on their membership? Can I even do this is Civi?

Answer (score 1):

I can not think of a way to limit the number of events based on a membership out of the box.

I would certainly add a custom field to a membership which I would then populate automatically based on the membership type with the CiviRules extension (more information here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/).

What CMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Wordpress

Comment: Would maybe using Activities rather than Events work better?